# Можно ли задать разный размер в двумерном массиве?

Tags: java, android

Есть массив:

```
byte[][] A = new byte[10][];
```

Как задать отличающиеся размеры (если возможно вообще) для массива?
Например

```
 [0][20],[1][50], [2][10], [3][1000].
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
byte[] b1 = new byte[20];
byte[] b2 = new byte[50];
byte[] b3 = new byte[10];
byte[] b4 = new byte[1000];
byte[][] A = new byte[][]{ b1, b2, b3, b4 };
```

Если размер известен только в момент вычисления:

```
byte sizeY =  (byte) (Math.random() * 100 ); // размер внешнего массива
byte[] x = new byte[ sizeY ]; // размеры внутренних массивов

for( int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++ ){  // вычисление размеров внутренних массивов
    x[i] = (byte) (Math.random() * 100);
}

byte[][] A = new byte[ sizeY ][];
for( int i = 0; i < sizeY; i++ ){ // создание двумерного массива
    A[i] = new byte[ x[i] ];
}
```

Comment: А если неизвестно количество одномерных массивов b1,b2,...bn заранее? Т.е. нужно задать массивы b1,b2,...bn не по отдельности.

Comment: Если количество элементов неизвестно, то Вам нужен не массив, а список.

Comment: Используется List, например, ArrayList, LinkedList

Comment: Про лист я знаю, но нужен именно массив.

Comment: Как Вы хотите сделать массив, если не знаете, сколько будет элементов? Это невозможно. Только список и потом переводить в массив

Comment: Например в процессе вычисления получается, что придется создать двумерный массив из 15 одномерных и размер каждого из них известен тоже из предыдущих вычислений.

Comment: Добавил в ответ

Comment: Спасибо! А то я уже хотел реализовать через Map.